# Rails Nginx config can not reach root url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, web-deployment

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

root /home/user/app/public;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Let's say my public ip: 111.111.111.111

When I try to enter the site 111.111.111.111/path, it works fine but when I try to enter only the root url 111.111.111.111 it gives me the "Welcome to nginx" message. I looked at the nginx log, but there is nothing about the root url.

I m also using unicorn, but I do not think there was a problem about that, I assume I ve added the necessary part of config here.

Comment: The "Welcome to nginx" should be the default index.html for the nginx installation.  You do have `$uri/index.html` in `try_files` as first, is this what you intended?  You can remove/rename either the index.html or remove/rename it in try_files - does that change the behaviour?

Comment: I ve removed it but nothing change. I do not understand why nothing comes in nginx log either

Comment: @RamazanZor try `location / { try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app; }`

Comment: it did not work, the interesting thing is, it still show me "Welcome to nginx" message even if I stop the nginx service in root url

Comment: I have found the problem, it is only because of browser cache, I ve deleted it and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be missing the unicorn .sock file:  see example nginx/unicorn/rails config here:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

You're referencing an `upstream` in your `proxy_pass` line but it's not defined.  Try adding this to the top:

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Unicorn SOCK file
  server unix:/path/to/your/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

I just looked at an app i did a while ago with rails, unicorn and nginx, and my entry for this was

```
server unix:/tmp/.sock fail_timeout=0;
```

It just depends how your unicorn is configured, as to where the sock file lives, so you'll need to tweak it to point to the right place.